# How do I check through the individual strings of a word in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

So I have this task that I'm kind of struggling with right now. I'm supposed to write a program which checks whether two word have the same vowels.
That's it's signature:

```
vowelEq :: String -> String -> Bool
```

In order to do this, I made a function called vowelCheck, which basically checks if a Char is a vowel and returns a boolean accordingly.

```
vowelCheck :: Char -> Bool
vowelCheck v | (v == 'a' || v == 'A') = True
             | (v == 'e' || v == 'E') = True
             | (v == 'i' || v == 'I') = True
             | (v == 'o' || v == 'O') = True
             | (v == 'u' || v == 'U') = True
             | otherwise = False
```

So far, that's what I've got:

```
vowelEq :: String -> String -> Bool
vowelEq s1 s2 | vowelCheck(head(s1)) == vowelCheck(head(s2)) = True
              | otherwise = False
```

It can only check whether the first Char of the word (head s1) is a vowel and if it's the same as on the other word. 
Now here's my problem: I don't know how to check the rest of the word. I had the idea to use tail recursively but that doesn't work with the signature of vowelEq (which I'm not allowed to change, mind you). Or just deleting the first element of the string would help tremendously, too.
But so far we've only learnt how to do very basic functions as well as how to declare data types, so not a whole lot of stuff.

I'm a total beginner and that's the first task we got for class, so I'd appreciate it if you explained your advice and solution!

Comment: "I'm supposed to write a program which checks whether two word have the same vowels."  What does that mean exactly? Same set of vowels? Same counts for all vowels? Same vowels in the same order?

Comment: So far, your attempt is going in the direction of  checking that the two strings have *a* vowel in the same position, the not the *same* vowel.

Comment: @Thilo It means the same set of vowels in the same order. I'm sorry for the confusion. So `vowelEq apple angle` should thus return `True`.     @chepner Welp, you're right! Hadn't thought of that! I don't have a particular idea of fixing that right now, but changing `vowelCheck` in a way that it returns another `Char` which then get compared should do the job, right?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `tail s1` to get the rest of the string (which may be empty).

Use that to call the function recursively with increasingly shorter strings (until the string is empty).

> the same set of vowels in the same order.

This means that you only need to look at the vowels: If a string starts with a non-vowel, you can just ignore that and continue with the `tail` for that string.

> I had the idea to use tail recursively but that doesn't work with the signature of vowelEq

Why not? The two tails are still two strings.

Comment: Yes! That was exactly what I wanted to do, however I thought that wouldn't work since tail returns a list and not a string.

Comment: @Readler: `type String = [Char]`. `String` is just another name for a list of characters, nothing more.

Comment: @chepner Well now I feel mighty stupid. So just to get back at my example, using `vowelEq(tail s1)` would then work to shorten the string each time? I'd check it myself, but unfortunately I'm on the road at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work:

```
isVowel c= or $ map (c==) ['a','A','e','E','i','I','o','O','U','u']
vowelEq a b = (filter isVowel a) == (filter isVowel b)
```

And to test:

```
vowelEq "behind" "rewind"
```